# How do I resize image directly while uploading the image?

Tags: 6, media

How do I resize image directly while uploading the image?

Select image from Computer > Upload > Resize directly to dimension that I want.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/manualcrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for crop image, then use **[Imagefield Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop)** module you can do that. Use image upload with crop as your widget after installing this module. Some other image crop modules are also available.

Comment: If the original image is 1mb and the resize image is 100kb. The total uploaded images to website is 1mb + 100kb or 100kb only? I am looking the resize module that upload resize image only. @Abin

Answer (score 1):

Try **[Max Image Size](https://www.drupal.org/project/max_image_size)** module

On the module page it says:

> This module will resize uploaded images to be below the set
>   dimensions. It is not an image style or other presentation layer
>   module. If you want to maintain the original image you should use
>   Image Resize Filter or an image style. The use case for this module is
>   sites where users may upload very large images, but you do not
>   want/need to keep the original.